# How to get the available space in a linux directory without displaying the "Avail" description

Tags: linux, bash

I want to get the available space for a particular directory and store it in a variable. I have this piece of code that returns the available space but has the "Avail" Description with it. I will not be able to use the variable for comparison because of that.

```
    df /backup/purging/resume/ | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

it returns

```
    Available
    70859076
```

I want a code that will only display the 70859076

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` can do it on its own:

```
df /backup/purging/resume/ | awk 'END{ print $4 }'
```

But `tail` offers a more general approach:

```
df /backup/purging/resume/ | awk '{ print $4 }' | tail -n 1
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two?

Comment: @Joey One tells `awk` to only print the last line. The other lets awk print everything and then pipes the output through tail which only prints the last line. The first is more efficient and concise while the second might be applicable to other tools which, unlike `awk` might lack a native way of printing the last line only.

Comment: Thanks, very comprehensive.

Comment: How can I put the value inside a variable? I tried doing this: DIRSPACE = df /backup/purging/resume/ | awk 'END{ print $4 }'   then echo $DIRSPACE, but returns DIRSPACE: command not found error. Sorry, im new to linux. Thanks

Comment: Hi, Thanks.. I got it. I was putting a space before and after the equal sign. That fixed my issue. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep -v` to exclude lines based on a pattern:

```
df /backup/purging/resume/ | grep -v Available | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working too. How can I put the value into a variable?